# Products attributes best relationship implementation Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

These tables represent a database schema with relationships between items, attributes, and attribute options. Here's a description of each table and their relationships:

**Attributes**
id: A unique identifier for each attribute.
name: The name of the attribute.

**Options** 
id: A unique identifier for each attribute option.
value: The value of the attribute option.
attribute_id: The foreign key referencing the id column in the attributes table.

**Items**  
id: A unique identifier for each item.
sku: The stock keeping unit (SKU) of the item.

**Items_options**

item_id: The foreign key referencing the id column in the items table.
option_id: The foreign key references the id column in the options table.

How can I get the attributes of the items? What is the Eloquent relationship between the `Item` and the `Attribute` models?

1- attributes `hasmany` attribute_options;
2- attribute_options `belongsto` attributes ;
3- items `belongstomany` attribute_options through third table items_attributes_options;
4- attribute_options `belongstomany` items through third table items_attributes_options;

Comment: What are you looking for? The Eloquent relationships? The models? what?

Comment: @KarlHill  The Eloquent relationships please, and thanks for vote down !!

Comment: I gave you the relationships.

Comment: @KarlHill the chat gpt answer was wrong and the relationship is not correct thank you for your comment!

Comment: Post the code you've tried.